# how to create a new hash collection from a model collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a collection of model objects that I need to convert into another collection but with many of the model's attributes removed.

Other than me looping through the existing collection and creating a new collection, is there a better way?

Say I have a user model like:

```
User id, name, password, country, city
```

And I want to create a new collection with the User model but with only the attributes: `id, name, country`

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Can you expand a little on your requirement? Do you need a collection of ActiveRecord instances? Why a copy? Do you mean a memory copy or a persistent copy?

Answer (score 0):

The .select method will only fetch the specified fields for the object:

```
users = User.select([:id, :name, :country])
```

So users is an array of all User objects with only id, name and country populated. Is that what you need?

Comment: That's right, just beware that doing this, your collection will be read only and if you'll try to read some properties that have not been selected, Rails will throw an `ActiveRecord::MissingAttributeError` exception.